# Why String Format does not work in c#

Tags: c#

```
string test="add number here {0}";
int number=7;
```

Why this does not work

```
String.Format(test,number);
string res=test;
```

but this work

```
String.Format("add number here {0}",number);
```

Comment: Why do you decide first example doesn't work? It works perfectly and produces the same result as second one.

Comment: Your code works fine: see [this example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/sFAP0e)

Answer (score 3):

Because you test it wrong. In thise 2 lines:

```
String.Format(test,number);
string res=test;
```

`String.Format` returns a string. As can be seen in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fht0f5be(v=vs.110).aspx) And this new string is the composed string with your number that you expect. If you assign the format string `test` to `res` and check whether `string res` has now the desired output. You will (of course) not find it but only

> "add number here {0}";

You need to use the return value of the method `String.Format`. There you will find the desired output:

```
string res = String.Format(test,number);
Console.WriteLine(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

Let me add few notes for you regarding the `String.Format`.

From the first code that you have added with the question, I hope that you misunderstand the usage of `String.Format`, As you expected it won't replace the placeholders in the input string with the objects. Actually It Replaces the placeholders with the arguments/objects and returns another string. So you have to look into the return value from the `.Format()` method for the actual formatted string.

That is why this doesn't work

```
String.Format(test,number);
string res=test;
```

Whereas this works fine:

```
string res = String.Format(test,number);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
test = String.Format(test,number);
```